# Erro url $feed->id

Tags: php, laravel, postgresql

Olá, estou trabalhando em um sistema com esquema de feed. Ao clicar em "Editar" aparece o seguinte erro:

> SQLSTATE[22P02]: Invalid text representation: 7 ERROR: invalid input
>   syntax for integer: "$feed->id" (SQL: select * from "feeds" where
>   "feeds"."id" = $feed->id limit 1)

Percebi que na URL onde era para ter algo como:

```
http://localhost:8000/feed/2/update
```

ele aparece como:

```
http://localhost:8000/feed/$feed->id/update
```

Como resolver isso? Espero que tenha deixado claro minha dúvida. Agradeço desde já.

Códigos:

**home.blade.php  (home)**

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')
<div class="container">
   @forelse($feeds as $feed)
      <h1>{{$feed->title}}</h1>
      <p>{{$feed->description}}</p>
      <b>Publicado por: {{$feed->user->name}}</b>
      <a href="{{url('/feed/$feed->id/update')}}">Editar</a>
      <hr>
   @empty
      <p>Nenhum chamado cadastrado!</p>
   @endforelse
</div>
@endsection
```

**web.php (rotas)**

```
<?php
Route::get('/', function () {
return view('auth/login');
});

Auth::routes();

Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');

Route::get('feed/{id}/update', 'HomeController@update');
```

**HomeController.php (controller)**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\feed;

class HomeController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('auth');
    }

    /**
     * Show the application dashboard.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index(feed $feed)
    {
        //$feeds = $feed->all();
        $feeds = $feed->where('user_id', auth()->user()->id)->get();

        return view('home', compact('feeds'));
    }

    public function update($idFeed)
    {
        $feed = feed::find($idFeed);

        return view('feed-update', compact('feed'));
    }
}
```

**feed-update.blade.php (view da feed)**

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')
<div class="container">
    <h1>{{$feed->title}}</h1>
    <p>{{$feed->description}}</p>
    <b>Publicado por: {{$feed->user->name}}</b>    
</div>
@endsection
```

Comment: Se possível poste seu código.

Comment: certo, são 3 arquivos do laravel, um momento.

Comment: Precisa só a linha que você define a URL. Provavelmente você gerou uma *string* mal formatada.

Comment: Ao meu ver está tudo certo, mas sou apenas iniciante então...

Comment: O problema está em `{{url('/feed/$feed->id/update')}}`. Utilize `{{url('/feed/'.$feed->id.'/update')}}` ou `{{url("/feed/{$feed->id}/update")}}`

Comment: Funcionou, muito obrigado.

Comment: Ao ROBERTO DE CAMPOS que está editando minha pergunta, retirando os argumentos de educação, respeito em primeiro lugar, e em segundo lugar, a proxima vez que for editar uma pergunda, adicione argumentos que sejam importantes.

Comment: @João.Mistura Esse é um entendimento da comunidade. https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/851/99718

Comment: Ok, não sabia vlw

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Acredito que o problema esteja neste trecho `<a href="{{url('/feed/$feed->id/update')}}">Editar</a>` do arquivo home.blade.php onde $feed->id está dentro de aspas simples. Tente da seguinte maneira:

```
<a href="{{url('/feed/' . $feed->id .'/update')}}">Editar</a>
```

Ou também:

```
<a href="{{url(sprintf( '/feed/%s/update', $feed->id ))}}">Editar</a>
```

Comment: Já funcionou, mas obrigado igual :)

Comment: funcionou com {{url('/feed/{$feed->id}/update')}}